# SwiftUI - Filter using .contains for a nested array of objects

Tags: arrays, swiftui, filter

I have an app that displays a large number of physically marked walking routes. Loads of fun. For my next release I'm planning to add filters to the map, to make it easier to find a route that matches users' wishes.

I have build a draft solution for that, but I'm sure there's a more efficient or clean way to do this. Thus I turn to you, the community, for a sanity check.

My setup data structure wise (unchangeable) - simplified to relevant-only for readability:

```
struct Location: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    let longitude, latitude: Double
    let routes: [Route]
}

struct Route: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id : Int
    let marking: String
    let distance: Double
}

class Locations: ObservableObject {
    var places: [Location]
    
    var primary: Location {
        places[0]
    }
    
    init () {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "locations", withExtension: "json")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        places = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Location].self, from: data)
        
    }
}
```

I load the array by calling `@StateObject var locations = Locations()`

I have an array of Location objects, which in turn include an array of Route objects (max 5).
Each route has a distance (length of the walk) attribute. I want to filter for a specific distance. Routes are ordered by length inside a Location. So the shortest walk at a specific location is `locations.place[xyz].route[0]`

I have a filter button setup that outputs a minDistance and maxDistance : Double that I feed into the filter func.

My current filter function solution checks index 0:

```
return locations.places.filter { location in
            (minDistance..<maxDistance).contains(location.routes[0].distance)
        }
```

This returns an array of locations where route[0] (the shortest walk at the location) matches the user's preferred walk length.

This means that I miss a fair amount of positive results. I feel like something like this should be possible, to check all routes at a location:

```
return locations.places.filter { location in
            (minDistance..<maxDistance).contains(location.routes[*].distance)
        }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Neither does .routes[0...5] or similar thoughts.

As I'm quite new at developing, and I only have short bursts of time to work on this app, I feel like I might be missing something very obvious here.

Is there a way to change the `.contains(location.routes[something-goes-here].distance)` check to test all (always at least 1 to max. 5 routes) routes in a place and not just index 0?

I tried inline changes like `(minDistance..<maxDistance).contains(location.routes[*].distance)` and `.contains(location.routes[(0...5)].distance)` but this gives me the error: Cannot convert value of type 'ClosedRange' to expected argument type 'Int'.

Which I understand, as the index indicator [] indeed does expect an Int.

I could use .count to loop through the nested routes, but this would result in a much more complex filter setup. I like the cleanliness of using the locations.places.filter `{ location in }` structure.

Comment: For starters, what are `places` as they're not in the data structures you show

Comment: Apologies, added above. It's the array [Location]. I tend to call a single Location a place too. It's weird how if you work on an app for a year+ you develop jargon, ha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more of your setup, it is difficult to test this solution, but the issue is that you are not iterating over all of your routes, as you are aware, and you can't do that using a range in an array, as you have found. Because we don't have a minimal reproducible example, I haven't been able to test this, but it should work. I would put the filter right into your `locations` class where it will be accessible from anywhere that can access `locations`. `.contains` will allow you to iterate over each element in the routes array. I have commented the code so you can see how it works:

```
class Locations: ObservableObject {
    var places: [Location]
    
    var primary: Location {
        places[0]
    }
    
    init () {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "locations", withExtension: "json")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        places = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Location].self, from: data)
        
    }
    
    func filterPlacesByDistance(minDistance: Double, maxDistance: Double) -> [Location] {
        // What you really want is to return all of your places that have at least 1
        // route within the distances set
        places.filter { place in
            // The filter gives you access to each place
            place.routes.contains { route in
                // .contains allows access to each route in a place.
                // then it is simply a matter of comparing each route.
                // if any match, this will return true for the .contains
                (minDistance..<maxDistance).contains(route.distance)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Using unnamed arguments, your filter becomes:

```
    func filterPlacesByDistance(minDistance: Double, maxDistance: Double) -> [Location] {
        places.filter { $0.routes.contains { (minDistance..<maxDistance).contains($0.distance) } }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome @Yrb! I like how you kept my original structure mostly intact, which means that I actually understand what you did. Makes your answer much more valuable to me, as it solves my problem but also teaches me a new thing: using a function in a class to clean up my code. It's awesome!

I had to switch things around a bit to make it all fit perfectly, but I now have it working solidly. The results are great, at least 30% more walks for every filter selection. Now just a few interface tweaks and animations to add and I can ship my most requested feature.